# creating table row element in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a response from server. It is a JSON object. 
I will create table row using this lines of code.

```
for(var i=0;i<Object.keys(obj.items).length;i++){
    str = str + "<tr><td>"+obj.items[i].C+"</td>";
    if(obj.items[i].S == "App"){
        str = str + "<td class='text-success'>";
    }else
    if(obj.items[i].S == "Rej"){
        str = str + "<td class='text-danger'>";
    }else
    if(obj.items[i].S == "Dr"){
        str = str + "<td class='text-warning'>";
    }else
    if(obj.items[i].Status == "Pending"){
        str = str + "<td class='text-muted'>";
    }
    str = str + obj.items[i].S+"</td><td>"+obj.items[i].D+"</td><td>"+obj.items[i].M+"</td>";
    if(obj.items[i].S == "App"){
        str = str + "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-default' disabled>Cancel</button> <button type='button' class='btn btn-default'>Print</button></td></tr>";
    }else
    if(obj.items[i].S == "Dr"){
        str = str + "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-default'>Edit</button><button type='button' class='btn btn-default'>Delete</button></td></tr>";
    }else
    if(obj.items[i].S == "Pending"){
        str = str + "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn default'>Cancel</button></td></tr>";
    }
}
```

But it is too long. Is there any better ways to create table row using jquery?

Here is the sample of JSON Object.

```
var obj = {"items":[{"C":"01","S":"Rej","D":"Jan 20","M":""}]};
    obj = {"items":[{"C":"02","S":"App","D":"Jan 21","M":"Jan 22"}]};
    obj = {"items":[{"C":"03","S":"Dr","D":"Jan 23","M":""}]};
    obj = {"items":[{"C":"04","S":"Pending","D":"Jan 24","M":""}]};
```

Here is final html sample,

```
<tr>
    <td>01</td>
    <td class="text-danger">Rej</td>
    <td>Jan 20</td>
    <td></td>
   <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you supply us with a few sample JSON Objects returned by the server? Also, more information about what sort of information can be parsed.

Comment: Please include a json response example and final html that you want

Comment: Good! Also, what are `C`, `S`, `D` and `M` mean?

Comment: Code, Status, Date, Modified

Comment: is it possible to make this in few lines? 5 - 10 lines?

Comment: I'd recommend using DIVs instead of tables. It's more flexible and can easily be responsive whereas tables can not be fully.

Comment: it is already responsive :)..

Comment: John, check out this example: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/no-more-tables-respsonsive-table As you can see by not using tables, you can do all kinds of great things in responsive like moving your column headers from a horizontal position to a vertical layout. Much more user friendly on a mobile device. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `tdLayoutMap` with keys which equal to conditions in your if else statements and values equal to html you are going to append:

```js
var obj = {"items":[{"C":"01","S":"Rej","D":"Jan 20","M":""}]};
    obj2 = {"items":[{"C":"02","S":"App","D":"Jan 21","M":"Jan 22"}]};
    obj3 = {"items":[{"C":"03","S":"Dr","D":"Jan 23","M":""}]};
    obj4 = {"items":[{"C":"04","S":"Pending","D":"Jan 24","M":""}]};

tdLayoutMap = {
  'App': ["<td class='text-success'>", "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-default' disabled>Cancel</button> <button type='button' class='btn btn-default'>Print</button></td></tr>"],
  'Rej': ["<td class='text-danger'>"],
  'Dr.': ["<td class='text-danger'>", "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-default'>Edit</button><button type='button' class='btn btn-default'>Delete</button></td></tr>"],
  'Pending': ["<td class='text-muted'>", "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn default'>Cancel</button></td></tr>"],
}
for(var i=0, str='';i<Object.keys(obj.items).length;i++){
    str = str + "<tr><td>"+obj.items[i].C+"</td>";
    str = str + tdLayoutMap[obj.items[i].S][0];
    str = str + obj.items[i].S+"</td><td>"+obj.items[i].D+"</td><td>"+obj.items[i].M+"</td>";
    str = str + tdLayoutMap[obj.items[i].S][1];
    alert(str);
}
```

Alternatively you can use [JS DOM Methods](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp) or [JQuery DOM Methods](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/) to interact with DOM.

Comment: can you add sample using JS and jQuery DOM methods?

Comment: and what is faster in loading? your answer or using JS and jQuery DOM methods?

Comment: @JohnArellano i think the fastest one would be my answer as it's forming string which directly injected into html. Have a good day :)

Comment: but why it is not a good practice? can you give sample using JS  and jquery DOM methods and the logic that you answered?

Comment: @JohnArellano you are right that's not recommended way, so i've updated my answer, actually the string concatenating is nice way to have best possible performance.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

<div id="showData"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var obj = [
            {"C":"01","S":"Rej","D":"Jan 20","M":""},
            {"C":"02","S":"App","D":"Jan 21","M":"Jan 22"},
            {"C":"03","S":"Dr","D":"Jan 23","M":""},
            {"C":"04","S":"Pending","D":"Jan 24","M":""}
        ];

var str = '';
$(obj).each(function(){
    str += "<tr><td>"+this.C+"</td>";
    if(this.S == "App"){
        str += "<td class='text-success'>";
    }else
    if(this.S == "Rej"){
        str += "<td class='text-danger'>";
    }else
    if(this.S == "Dr"){
        str += "<td class='text-warning'>";
    }else
    if(this.Status == "Pending"){
        str += "<td class='text-muted'>";
    }
    str += this.S+"</td><td>"+this.D+"</td><td>"+this.M+"</td>";
    if(this.S == "App"){
        str += "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-default' disabled>Cancel</button> <button type='button' class='btn btn-default'>Print</button></td></tr>";
    }else
    if(this.S == "Dr"){
        str += "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-default'>Edit</button><button type='button' class='btn btn-default'>Delete</button></td></tr>";
    }else
    if(this.S == "Pending"){
        str += "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn default'>Cancel</button></td></tr>";
    }
})

$('#showData').html(str);
</script>
```

You obj is easier to handle as an array of objects. And you can use the variable "this" to represent each object in the loop.

Also, you were overwriting your obj variable for each individual object. I'm guess you meant to add each object, not overwrite each time?